# Java RunTimeException and ClassNotFoundException Error

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app with a splash screen but every time I run it I get an exception. After the splash screen appears, a menu screen is supposed to appear. However when I run it in the emulator it comes up with the message "stopped working" because of these exceptions.

This is the log I get from running the app.

```
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203): Process: com.example.f1app, PID: 1203
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.f1app/com.example.f1app.SplashActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.f1app.SplashActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.f1app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.f1app.SplashActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.f1app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     ... 10 more
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.f1app.SplashActivity
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):         ... 13 more
04-21 20:36:25.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

This is the Android Manifest XML file:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.f1app"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="10"
            android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/f1logo"
            android:label="@string/F1App"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
           <activity
                android:name="com.example.F1App.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_mainscreen" >



            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.F1App.HelpScreen"
                android:label="@string/title_helpscreen" >


            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.F1App.SplashActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.F1App.EventScreen"
                android:label="@string/title_eventdetails"
                 >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.F1App.TicketScreen"
                android:label="@string/title_booktickets_screen"
                 >
            </activity>

        </application>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
         </manifest>
```

I have no clue where to solve my error, do you?

Answer (score 2):

In the AndroidManifest file you have declared:

```
android:name="com.example.F1App.SplashActivity"
```

Can you please changed it to:

```
android:name="com.example.f1app.SplashActivity"
```

Comment: It still comes up with the "stopped" message

Comment: @footballgeek Can you change and the other activities name as well with this prefix: android:name="com.example.f1app.", i.e: android:name="com.example.f1app. HelpScreen", android:name="com.example.f1app.MainActivity", android:name="com.example.f1app.EventScreen", android:name="com.example.f1app.TicketScreen"

Comment: @footballgeek And if the above doesn't work can you change the package name capital letters?

Comment: I've changed them as well and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is it something to do with the layout of the android manifest.xml file

Comment: @footballgeek The problem is that the names on the AndroidManifest files doesn't match with the package declaration and therefore can't find the classes

Answer (score 0):

In you manifest the fully qualified name for the activity is `android:name="com.example.F1App.SplashActivity"`. While you try to launch `com.example.f1app.SplashActivity`. Please try fixing this inconsistency in letter cases.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same problem, and I decided to take the easy way out.

Step 1: Rename the project you are presently having this error to some other name so that you don't lose files or useful code in it (how to rename the file: go to the folder where your android studio projects are saved on your PC and locate the file, e.g., `c/users/john/AndroidStudio`).

Step 2: Create a new project and give it the name of the previous error project. Now this won't be a duplicate project since you already renamed the original project in step 1 to something else.

Step 3: Open both projects and copy all previous files/code starting with your manifest to the new project (there won't be name conflicts because the new project has the right name). After each stage of copying a file, test the app and see that it runs perfectly before you copy another file.